# JS: getElementByID wildcard

Tags: javascript, class

I have a table and a button.
If i click the button, all `<tr>` which have an id starting with "tr" (in the example the first 3) should be set to `display = "none";`

Here is a  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHSwJ/8/)

Has anyone a Idea how i get this to work?

Comment: i use a class in the fiddle?

Comment: Then why do you need to use the ID? Just use `getElementsByClassName` to get a list of them.

Comment: okay, an then i can use `document.getElementsByClassName("tr").style.Display= "None";`?

Comment: No, you have to write a `for` loop.

Comment: But you have `class="tr"` on the 4th one, which shouldn't be selected. You need to give the ones you want a class that only they have.

Comment: how can this loop be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give all the elements that have `id="tr_NNNN"` a distinct class, e.g. `class="tr tr_NNNN"`. Then use the following loop:

```
var hide_trs = document.getElementsByClassName('tr_NNNN');
for (var i = 0; i < hide_trs.length; i++) {
    hide_trs[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through your tr elements using the IDs:

```
    function doJS() {
      for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i ++) {
        document.getElementById("tr_" + i).style.display="none";
      }
    }
```

Comment: but the problem is, in me real application its like "Tr_299AB993" so the counting would not work..

Comment: In that case you must have some sort of logic how to determine which <tr> elements to remove. like class="remove" or similar. Then you could use document.getElementsByClassName to get the items marked to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't supply a wildcard to gEBI, but you can use the attribute starts with selector in qSA:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='tr_']")[0].style.display="none";
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP asked but actually not what should be done. Use `class` instead.

Comment: I agree if you have control over the code.  Sometimes you are stuck in an inflexible legacy system, though, so it may be worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using classes instead of IDs for this, but this should satisfy your original question:

```
function doJS() {

var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
    var row = rows[i];
    if(row.getAttribute("id") && /^tr/.test(row.getAttribute("id"))){
       row.style.display = 'none';   
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHSwJ/14/

And while this isn't a jQuery question, I would point out that by leveraging jQuery, this can be reduced to:

```
 $('tr[id^="tr"]').css('display', 'none');
```